# Laravel queuing jobs with Redis

Tags: laravel

Do I have to run migrations for creating jobs table and failed_jobs?

```
php artisan queue:table
php artisan queue:failed-table
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jobs` table is used when your queue driver is `database`. (Since you're using Redis you don't have to have this)

`failed_jobs` is used when your queue jobs fail to run. It's good to have this table so that you can track jobs that failed.

Comment: but how am i going to track them when they are not even written to DB? When you run php artisan queue:work redis....the jobs are not written to DB

Comment: So, what you want to say is that even if i am not using database queue if a job fails with redis it will be written in failed_jobs table?

Comment: Yes that's correct, even if you are not using ```database``` as queue driver, if job fails with redis, it will be written in ```failed_jobs``` table

Comment: OK, one last question, how can i deliberately provoke a failed job so i can see this and test it?

Comment: Make an error in your code. Example: echo out an undefined variable inside a job so that it will fail.